# VBA (MS Access) Remove whitespace from string and start next word with upper case

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to convert a "title" which can have whitespaces in it like `" this is a Test   title   "` to a string where all whitespaces are removed and the words which were previously separated by the whitspaces are all starting with capital letters.
The result of the above string should be `"ThisIsATestTitle"`.

Goal is to create a string which then can be used as a folder name for the filesystem.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MsAccess VBA:

```
replace(strconv(" this is a Test   title   ",vbProperCase)," ","")
```

returns **ThisIsATestTitle**

Thanks @June7 for giving this useful info:

> If expression in query or textbox, use 3 in place of vbProperCase.

Comment: If expression in query or textbox, use 3 in place of vbProperCase.

Answer (score 2):

> Goal is to create a string which then can be used as a folder name for the filesystem.

Then you have a few more things to do.

Non-trailing spaces are not a problem, but a lot of other characters are. In particular, you need to remove all occurences of `<`, `>`, `:`, `"`, `/`, `\`, `|`, `?` and `*`.

There are a few special edge cases as well: For example, you can't use any of the "reserved names" (`COM1` etc.) and your name must not end with a period. For a full list, see Microsoft's official documentation:

- [Windows App Development: Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)